# React-Native Stripe SDK

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I have RN App that use stripe SDK for payment, after long time testing have no problem. But yesterday I got the error when generating token from stripe SDK. I will provide bellow the code and the error message. If someone here have the same problem and know the solution I appreciate so much if you want to help me.

Source code to generate token

```
//useStripe hooks from stripe SDK
const { createToken } = useStripe();

// function to generate Token 
const generateToken = async () => {
        const token = await createToken({
            type: 'Card',
            currency: 'brl',
            address: {
                city: payload.city,
                postalCode: payload.cep,
                state: payload.state,
            },
            name: payload.nameOnCard
        })
        return token
    }

// generate the token
const token = await generateToken();
```

And here the error message when execute `generateToken()`

```
 {"error": {"code": "Failed", "declineCode": null, "localizedMessage": "There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds", "message": "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.", "stripeErrorCode": "", "type": "invalid_request_error"}}
```

If anyone here maybe know this problem caused of stipe membership or something else, please let me know here. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the stripe dashboard by the account holder there's no change about. Then I try to figure out what is the problem. And what I found is about the `StripeProvider` component is wrong, and for the previous version that work is because app cache in react-native, and after I run `react-native run ios --reset-cache` the error appears. So after I fixing the `StripeProvider` component the app working again.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the API key is missing in the request, so I'd suggest you to check if a valid `publishableKey` is provided when you initialized the Stripe SDK.

You can specify a `publishableKey` via [StripeProvider](https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/index.html#StripeProvider) or [initStripe](https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/index.html#initStripe).

Comment: It's weird because I never touch the configuration or change the publisable key. Even I have tried to hard coded the publishable key on StripeProvider but not happen anything.

Comment: Can you check the log in your Stripe Dashboard, and paste here the exact request your app sent and also the response returned from Stripe server?

Comment: Ok, I will ask to the account holder to check it.